# Should I convert my repetitive string data to integers to help performance?

Tags: mongodb, performance

I have around 900M records with 17 or so string fields. Most of those fields contain one of several possible values. For example, there is a gender field. It contains “M”, “F”, “U”. My question is, if I replace these values with integer values, would that help with performance when querying?

Some of my other fields are longer, up to 20+ characters. Another field contains a range of income, for example “$50,000 - $75,000”. We have 13 different income ranges. Many of our queries are along the lines of, “give me everyone who has an income between $50,000 to $125,000”. What I’m doing now is performing and $in query where I pass in each income range that fits, for example: ‘$50,001 - $ 75,000’, ‘$75,001 - $ 100,000’, ‘$100,001 - $ 125,000’.

Again, if I replace these string values with integers, would that help performance?

**EDIT**

To add more color to the question:

These fields are various demographic data (age, gender, marital status, income, house value, etc.) The raw data we get is in string format. Even age is a string because we have "99+". I can easily interpret these strings into my own set of numbers so that income of ‘$50,001 - $ 75,000’ would become number 3, for example.

The end user has a web UI that allows them to select values from one or more fields to query. The query is built using the MongoDB C# driver.

A typical query would look like this:

```
{
    "MaritalStatus": {
        "$in": [
            "M"
        ]
    },
    "Age": {
        "$in": [
            "70",
            "71",
            "72",
            "73"
        ]
    },
    "Income": {
        "$in": [
            "$ 250,001 - $ 500,000",
            "$ 500,000 OR MORE"
        ]
    },
    "HomeValue": {
        "$in": [
            "$1,500,000 - $1,999,999",
            "$2,000,000 OR MORE"
        ]
    },
    "Zip": {
        "$in": [
            "90210"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: In the case of the income ranges, it would probably have been better to put the range texts in another table and link them with an id. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization. Changing it though, may not give you much of a performance gain. If you can be more specific about what queries you need to be faster, you're more likely to get useful suggestions.

Comment: @SimonGoater I normally do a linked table when working in relational DBs, which I do quite often. I'm honestly a bit of a MongoDB neophyte. The queries are created by end users via a web UI. They might select a list of vales for upwards of 7-8 fields. And they even have the option to "OR" some of the fields. I'll see if I can add some more details into the question. But in reality I want to simply know if having indexes with integers is better than having indexes with strings in MongoDB.

Comment: It might save some storage space, but I doubt it will make a huge difference to queries that can either use indexes or scan the whole table. What I've done before is restrict the types of queries that users can submit to one's I know how to execute using indexes efficiently. Other than that, there's partitioning the table (if you can on MongoDB) putting each partition on it's own device. This kind of solution would require some testing to see if it worth doing.  Also, there are other hardware based improvements such as using RAID and/or faster storage devices (NVME SSDs).

Comment: There is sharding in MongoDB, but that's only applicable if you have multiple servers, I believe. We have 1 server and it has NVME SSDs and 256GB of RAM. Unfortunately this system must allow the users to query however they wish. I do have several indexes to cover the most common query groups. I think at the least you're correct about index size, which may help overall given the number of indexes I have. I plan to test this theory by creating another collection that is the same dataset but been encoded into integers, but that'll have to wait until sometime in January.

Comment: If you have 10 indexes, each requiring 20 bytes per record for say 1B records, that's 200GB. If you have enough memory to put all your indexes in memory, I suspect that would help. Maybe some more RAM would be a good idea?